# Left and right multiplication for Cayley graphs

Tags: group-theory, graph-theory, finite-groups, cayley-graphs

Correct me if I am wrong but I have written down the following:

Let $X$ be a finite group, with subset $S$ and corresponding Cayley graph $G$.

The edge set for a Cayley graph is defined such that two vertices $g, h \in  G$ are joined by a directed edge from $g$ to $h$ if $gh^{-1} \in S$. Then $gh^{-1}h = g$. So a directed edge only occurs if  $g = sh $ in $X$.

From this, I see that left multiplication of an element in $S$ sends a directed edge into that element, would I be correct in saying that right multiplication of an element in $S$ sends the directed edge away from the element, i.e: $(g,h)$ is an edge if from $g$ to $gs = h$.

If so this would be easier to imagine as multiplication by elements in the generating set send the corresponding vertices to the product of that element with a generator.

Is there any way to prove this? I know it works for the Dihedral group but am not sure if it is true for the general case.

I have used the definition on Wolfram Alpha for a Cayley graph.

Thanks in advance

Comment: The directed edge is from $h$ to $g$ in your case, $(gh^{-1})h = g$ means you start from $h$, act by the element $gh^{-1}\in S$ and end up at $g$.  The movement is from $h$ to $g$.

Comment: There are variations in definitions of the Cayley graph from different sources. I am most familiar with the definition that there is an edge (labeled $s$) form $g$ to $h$ if $h=gs$, which is different from the one you got from the Wolfram site. With the Wolfram definition, $G$ acts on the right as isometries of the graph, whereas with my definition it acts on the left. But, note that, provided that $S$ is closed under inversion, $gs=h \Rightarrow s^{-1}g^{-1} = h^{-1}$ so the two versions of the graph are isomorphic using the mapping $g \leftrightarrow g^{-1}$.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on Derek's comment (we both read between the lines that by "sending edges" you were getting at possible Cayley graph isomorphisms induced by left or right multiplication).

The left-right asymmetry is a little confusing.  If our Cayley graph *edges* are defined (as in the Wolfram article) by *left* multiplication, then 
*right* multiplication will give graph isomorphisms.  However, if our Cayley graph *edges* are defined 
(as by Derek) by *right* multiplication, then *left* multiplication will give graph isomorphisms.
But we cannot have it both ways: for a fixed Cayley graph definition it will not generally be the case that 
left *and* right multiplications are graph isomorphisms.

Using the Wolfram definition, from the existence of edge
$$
x \stackrel{s}{\rightarrow} y,
$$
it follows at once that $sx=y$ and thus $s(xg)=yg$, so there exists edge
$$
xg \stackrel{s}{\rightarrow} yg.
$$
Thus each $g \in X$ "sends edges" to other edges in the true sense of a graph isomorphism. (It gives two maps, 
one on vertices and one on edges that respects the graph incidence).

Consider the simplest case of dihedral group $D_3$, where $S$ is made up of 
$60^{\circ}$ rotation $a$ and vertical reflection $b$.  Below is the Cayley graph for $(D_3, S)$.

[image: Cayley graph of dihedral group $D_3$]

Here's a simple counterexample: While edge $e \stackrel{a}{\rightarrow} a$, is sent via right multiplication by $b$ 
to edge $b \stackrel{a}{\rightarrow} ab$, no edge exists of the form
$$
b \stackrel{a}{\rightarrow} ba,
$$
since $ab\neq ba$. Thus left multiplication by $b$ does not yield a well-defined graph morphism: it permutes the 
vertices but not the vertices and edges in concert.

Comment: thank you for your answer, and i have a follow up question, as the set defined for the cayley graph is closed under inversion, can I state that both left and right multiplication can coincide for a cayley graph if we include multiplication by elements of inverses, so for the dihedral group, multiplying on the right by a^-1

Comment: would that imply that both could be well defined on the same cayley graph

Comment: Hmm, one thing is pretty clear: the isomorphism Derek gives $x\mapsto x^{-1}$ on vertices and similarly for edges is *not* of the form left or right multiplication by some $a$ (otherwise $a=e$ and $X$ is trivial).  Not all Cayley graph isomorphisms arise as left (right) multiplication.  It's analogous to how the symmetric group on a group is much bigger than the group but "contains" it by the left multiplications (famously by Cayley's Thm).  Likewise the $Aut(G)$ contains $X$ by right multiplications, but is generally bigger.

Comment: Thank you I am still a bit confused and am struggling a bit, I have just posted a question of one of my attempted proofs and was hoping you could take a look at it